# Stata : how to use variables as file name

Tags: stata

I would like to use a variable (its value) as file name. Any ideas? Im using stata 14

Thanks a Lot in advance!

Comment: To improve the Quality of your Question, please give an indication of what research you have performed into your problem, with particular reference to be given to any particularly helpful source (with links).  Please show us what code you are trying and a description of the results, including the full text of any error messages produced.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to ask a good question.

Comment: So, what is the problem? What's a legal filename is up to your (unstated) operating system. Feel free to use whatever is legal and helpful. I can't see the Stata issue here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment from @toonice, please do give more details and I can better address your question.

However, you can use local macros to input into file names. Let's say you have a data set of a single variable `x` taking values of your filenames. You could loop through the data to save different files with the values of `x`. For example:

```
local N = _N
forvalues i = 1/`N' {
    local myfilename x[`i']
    // Insert code that changes data in some way to make files different
    save ../output/`myfilename'_staticfilename.dta, replace
}
```

Give me more context and I am happy to provide more help.

Comment: You need an equals sign in the `local` call.